# Facebook Comments Plugin - Tagging & Notifications

Tags: facebook, social-networking, tagging

I'm building a website where I plan on writing product details/reviews for businesses, and I'd like to include a Facebook Comments plugin to get feedback.

But I want to know, if someone gets tagged in the comments part of my website, do they get a notification on facebook? Or, does anyone know if there is a way to make this possible?

Alternatively, is there a way of letting other people see the comments that are made to the comments box of a a specific page?

Meaning... If I worte about `Business One`, could I some how set something up to ensure that `Business One` could be notified about comments made to their profile page via Facebook?

Comment: For comments made outside of Facebook, there are no notifications about mentions. Maybe with Comment Mirroring, which mirrors all comments to posts you make to your FB page this could be possible. (Don't know for sure, you'd have to check/test.)